# How to get inside running geth console?

Tags: go-ethereum

So I already run geth. And I quit. I don't remember how I quit, maybe I typed with exit or ctrl+c.

Anyway, now I can see geth running when I type [ top ] command in console terminal of ubuntu 16.04 server.

Now how can I go to inside of geth console?
Thanks.

[ geth console ] 
command just spit out errors says, 
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: datadir already used by another process

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do `geth attach ipc:/tmp/geth/geth.ipc` to connect back to the geth console

Note: the IPC path must be provided